# python: sub() function usage

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Input**:

```
[‘PQRSTU’, ‘2018-07-18T11:37:48’, ‘2015-01-24T10:00:00’]
```

**Intended Output (‘T’ has to be replaced by ‘ ’)**

```
[‘PQRSTU’, ‘2018-07-18 11:37:48’, ‘2015-01-24 10:00:00’]
```

**Sample Code**

```
def replaceT(row):
    p = re.compile('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}')    
    print (p.sub('????', str(row)))
```

Question – what should be the first parameter in sub() to return the intended output?

Comment: Search for "capturing groups"

Comment: There is nothing you can use in place of those `????` to get the correct output.

Comment: `.replace("T", "  ")` will work here. You don't the the hammer.

Comment: @styvane `PQRSTU` would be changed to `PQRS U`. Maybe a fix to this is to `try` to parse the date. If no exception is raised, use `.replace("T", " ")`. In case of format exception, just pass.

Comment: Maybe just a problem in the question, not in the code, but the first elements in those lists are not in proper quotes. (Makes me wonder: if this a list of strings, or a string that looks (almost) like a list of strings?

Answer (score 0):

You can use capturing groups. In my example I have two groups I'm referencing in `re.sub` by `\1` and `\2`:

```
import re

l = ["PQRSTU", "2018-07-18T11:37:48", "2015-01-24T10:00:00"]
l = [re.sub(r'(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})', r'\1 \2', v) for v in l]

print(l)
```

Outputs:

```
['PQRSTU', '2018-07-18 11:37:48', '2015-01-24 10:00:00']
```

Comment: Thanks - it was very helpful. Based on your suggestion:  def replaceT(row):
   print (re.sub(r'(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})', r'\1 \2', str(row)))